# why app crashes when I use localization and LocationButton in swiftui? I get this error:Thread 1: "Invalid parameter not satisfying: width && height"

Tags: swift, xcode, swiftui, localizable.strings

In my app I used locationButton and everything worked fine. Then I added Localizable string file and localized for English. Still, everything worked OK. Then I added localized String file for Hebrew, and it compiles, opens my simulator and shows everything in Hebrew But then I try to use the app and click something and it crashes and gives me this error:
`Thread 1: "Invalid parameter not satisfying: width && height"`.
Can't find anything about this anywhere. Did anyone encountered this?

The String files:

English:

```
 /* 
Localizable.strings
*/
"location" = "Location:";
```

Hebrew:

```
"location" = "מיקום:";
```

This is my code:

```
import SwiftUI
import MapKit
import CoreLocationUI

struct ContentView: View { 

  @StateObject var vm = ViewModel() 

  var body: some View {
       VStack { 
           Text("location")
           LocationButton(.currentLocation) { vm.reqestUserLocationOnce() } 
                .foregroundColor(.white)
                .symbolVariant(.fill)
                .labelStyle(.iconOnly)
                .clipShape(Capsule()) 
       }
   }
}

class ViewModel: NSObject, ObservableObject, CLLocationManagerDelegate {

   private let locationManager = CLLocationManager()
    override init() {
        super.init()
        locationManager.delegate = self
        locationManager.desiredAccuracy = kCLLocationAccuracyBest
    }
    func reqestUserLocationOnce() { locationManager.requestLocation() }
    func locationManager(_ manager: CLLocationManager, didUpdateLocations locations: [CLLocation]) {
         guard let currenLocation = locations.last else { return }
         CLGeocoder().reverseGeocodeLocation(currenLocation) { placemarks, error in
             guard error == nil else { return }
             guard let placemark = placemarks?.first else { return }
             guard placemark.location?.coordinate != nil else { return }
         }
   }
  func locationManager(_ manager: CLLocationManager, didFailWithError error: Error) { print(error.localizedDescription) }
}
```

Comment: Welcome to SO - Please take the [tour](https://stackoverflow.com/tour) and read [How to Ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) to improve, edit and format your questions. 

Without a [Minimal Reproducible Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) it is impossible to help you troubleshoot.